# Finding the perceptual redundancy inside a color image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, redundancy, perception

How to find the perceptual redundancy in color images in matlab? Is there any piece of code available or a systematic approach available which can only output the perceptually indiscernible image taking the input of the color image with perceptual redundancy.

Or how to find the just noticeable color difference in R, G, B axis in Matlab? Need a systematic approach to do this.